# Windows Embedded Compat 7 support for Native 80211 IHV Extensions DLL?

Tags: native, windows-embedded-compact, wifi

We are developing WIFI miniport  driver for Windows Embedded Compat 7. Plan is  to extend the security features supported by Native 80211 framework through IHV Extensions DLL. But didn't find any resource specifying WEC 7 support for IHV Extensions Dll.

Pls let us know whether WEC 7 supports it and any resource for developing. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add some more related tags native alone is pointless.

Comment: With further investigation we came to know that WEC7 has support for IHV Extension DLLs. But still unclear whether the host supplicant has support for IHV UI Extensions DLL.we need info mainly on how to establish link between Wlan Driver, IHV Extensions and IHV UI Extensions DLL for WEC7. Please help to crack this.Thanks.